# How to pass a value between UITableViews

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have 2 UITable view controller links with push style. The first one is a static table view and set style to right detail when I tap on it. It will pass the data from the detail to the second UITable view controller for editing the value. once finish editing. tab the back button and the value will passing back to the first UITable view controller.

I am using this when tap on the first table view controller

```
 NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[myDefaults setObject:myString forKey:@"amount"];
[myDefaults synchronize];
```

and retrieve it from (void)viewdidload on the second UItable view controller

```
NSString *recoveredString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"amount"];
```

But it does not work when I return to the first table view. it does not refresh with the new value pass from second table view.

am I using the correct method of passing data in between two table view? if wrong what is your suggestion?

Comment: I am no=t clear about when the actions occur - as you have the data change in a separate sentence and I can't see if they refer to the UI action before or after it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use notifications to push data. What I do is create a shared singleton class for both UITableViews to access. Then one UITableView can send a notifcation to the other view to tell it to read from the singleton class. I always like to hear other ways of doing it though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delegates to pass values back from view controllers regardless of whether they were pushed via a navigation controller or shown modally.  Something like:

MyEditController.h:

```
@class MyEditController;

@protocol MyEditControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)myEditController:(MyEditController *)myEditController
            updatedThing:(Thing *)thing;
- (void)myEditController:(MyEditController *)myEditController
            deletedThing:(Thing *)thing;
@end

@interface MyEditController : UITableViewController
{
    id<MyEditControllerDelegate> _delegate;
    Thing *_thing;
    ...
}

@property (assign, nonatomic, readwrite) id<MyEditControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (retain, nonatomic, readwrite) Thing *thing;
...

@end
```

MyEditController.m:

```
...

- (void)updateThing
{
    ...
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myEditController:updatedThing:)])
    {
        [_delegate myEditController:self updatedThing:self.thing];
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)deleteThing
{
    ...
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myEditController:deletedThing:)])
    {
        [_delegate myEditController:self deletedThing:self.thing];
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

...
@end
```

Now in the *parent* view controller you do:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     MyEditController *myEditController = [[[MyEditController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
     myEditController.delegate = self;
     myEditController.thing = [self.thingList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:myEditController animated:YES];
}
- (void)myEditController:(MyEditController *)myEditController
            updatedThing:(Thing *)thing
{
    // Update thing in self.thingList
    // Reload table view row
}

- (void)myEditController:(MyEditController *)myEditController
            deletedThing:(Thing *)thing
{
    // Delete thing from self.thingList
    // Delete table view row
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am still figuring out how to apply this